# Spring: No such instance field

Tags: java, spring

Существует интерфейс репозитория:

```
@Repository
public interface MailLogRepo extends JpaRepository<MailLog, Long> {
}
```

Этот заавтовайрен в сервисный класс и там вызывается:

```
@Autowired
MailLogRepo mailLogRepo;

...

mailLogRepo.save(log);
```

При дебаге в окне дебага пишет:

```
mailLogRepo = No such instance field:'mailLogRepo'
```

Сохранение в базу не происходит.
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: мало инфы для ответа... во-первых, как вы инициализируете спринг? может спринг просто бины не создает из указанных классов и интерфейсов, потому как просто их не находит. во-вторых, выложите полностью класс сервиса. в-третьих, как вы используете сам сервис? как вы создаете его объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, старый варник как-то криво ставился. Переустановил варник в tomcat -всё заработало.

Comment: Если вы имплементируете `JpaRepository` аннотация `@Repository` не обязательно. Бин сам добавляться спрингов в контекст

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/212903)

Comment: @Эдуард очень похоже на попытку ответа. Тем более, сам автор и отвечает — как по вашему он будет просить у себя внести уточнения? Если вы считаете, что ответ ошибочный или неполный — расскажите, чем его можно улучшить.

Comment: Век живи - век учись! Представить страшно, сколько бы я еще мучился, если бы не нашел этот вопрос здесь. ТС спасибо за ответ!